# jQuery set element style on a loop

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "app_name" : "yeah",
  },
  "template" : {
    "pages" : [
      {
        "styles" : [
          {
            "background_color" : "transparent"
          },
          {
            "background_image" : "url('http://desktopbackground.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Blurred-Background-for-android.jpg')"
          },
          {
            "background_size" : "cover"
          },
          {
            "background_position" : "center center"
          },
          {
            "height" : "auto"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to apply the styles inside the page array dynamically to the page using a loop, with the following function:

```
jQuery.each(styles, function(index, style) {
         for (property in style) {
            page_content = jQuery(page_content).first('div').css(property, style[property]);
         }
})
```

The problem is that the loop is replacing the style attribute entirely after every loop, instead I need to keep the existing content of the style attribute and adding a new attribute each loop, not replacing the existing ones.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try ...first('div').css({property: style[property]});

Comment: @artm may you show the entire answer? I tried this method but it does not work. Thanks

Comment: you will notice that `property` is a numeric index inside the for loop, whereas `style[property]` is an object with just one property. I recommend putting in some logging (`console.log`) to see what you're dealing with. If you can alter the JSON, do that, so you are dealing with one styles object having several properties. Then use the jQuery css method as per http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Answer (score 0):

Just an untested thought, not sure if it makes a difference but have you tried the object parameter version of .css()? Something like this:

```
var appendCss = {};
jQuery.each(styles, function(index, style) {
    for (property in style) {
        appendCss[property] = style[property];
    }
});

page_content = jQuery(page_content).first('div').css(appendCss);
```

Comment: nothing, still only the last item in the loop is added

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(property, style[property]`? While you're at it, try to log the `appendCss` var as well, it should look like a flattened version of your original `styles` array.

Comment: appendCss is a different object on each loop and the method .css ends up adding always the last object in the loop

Comment: Managed to try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/irot/ne2v2tt8/); I misunderstood what was going on in the `jQuery.each`. Updated my answer, see if that works.

Comment: Well then, to weed out the obvious first: is `jQuery(page_content).first('div')` returning a valid element? Because while I've never used the `.first()` function, the API shows that it doesn't accept any arguments: [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
jQuery.each(styles, function(index, style) {
    for (property in style) {
        var original_style = jQuery(page_content).find('#'+page_id).attr('style');
        if(!original_style)
            original_style = '';
        var style = property + ':' + style[property] + ';';
        jQuery(page_content).find('#'+page_id).attr('style', style + original_style);
    }
});
```